# Add an incrementing number to end of string in python

Tags: python

I am trying to add an incrementing number to the end of a string and apply this to every row in one column of my dataframe. The column has 76 rows. Ideally I want the output to look like this:

```
Event Reference Number
FEBRUARY_2019_1
FEBRUARY_2019_2
FEBRUARY_2019_3
```

I am trying to use apply with a lambda function but am stuck trying to figure out the next step.

```
df_Trade_File['Event Reference Number'].apply(lambda x: enumerate(df_Trade_File['Event Reference Number']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas.Series.str.cat)

```
df["Event Reference Number"] = df["Event Reference Number"].str.cat(map(str, df.index), sep='_')
```

If you're using an index other than standard index replace `map(str, df.index)` with a range but make it all strings or python will yell at you:

```
map(str, range(1, df.shape[0]+1))
```

Comment: I get a raise ValueError when I use this: raise ValueError("Did you mean to supply a `sep` keyword?")

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note is that for the change to take affect you will need to set your df to the result at which time you could use apply or something to format it but in this situation you could probably do something simpler like:

```
df_Trade_File['Event Reference Number'] = df_Trade_File['Event Reference Number'] + '_' + str(df.index)
```

assuming you are using a standard index of 1-76.

Comment: Nice answer, I hope you don't mind but I stole your `df.index` idea. It makes the line shorter and cleaner assuming generic index ofc

Comment: This is what gets returned in each row when I use that: "FEBRUARY_2019__Int64Index([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75], dtype='int64')"